# a formula about conic bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $\pi:Z\to S$ be a conic bundle over a smooth complex surface $S$. I'd like to know how to prove that $-\pi_{*}K_{Z}^{2}=4K_{S}+\Delta$, where $\Delta$ denotes the locus in $S$ over which the fibres are singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of sources, or you could just prove this for yourself.  In the context of algebraic geometry, this follows from  Proposition 5.1(v) of [Divisor Classes and The Virtual Canonical Bundle for Genus 0 Curves](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602642v1.pdf) by de Jong and myself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also found other sources such as Mori and Mukai's paper "On Fano 3-folds with B_{2}>=2",Adv. Stud. Pure Math. 1 101--129(1983).